# Concatenate a variable with a string

Tags: string-manipulation, number-representation, output-formatting

I have a little problem with a variable and a string. I built a game with a panel that shows a random word,the player clicks "Yes" if he knows the meaning and clicks "No" otherwise. When the game ends a message is displayed.

Here's a part of my code:

```
l=10; *number of words you want to play with*
click=0;
p=39176(click/l);

Row[{Button["Yes", click++], 
  Button["No"],Button["End game",m=StringJoin["You played with ",ToString[l]," "," words, and you know ", ToString[click],"words.\nThe Mathematica´s WordList has 39176 words, so you technically know ",ToString[p]," words."];Print[m]]}]
```

I got this message when I finish the game:
[image]

The problem is how " p" is shown. I tried with "...ToString[NumberForm[per,5]]..." but didn't work.

I appreciate your help.

Thanks!

DONE. Adding "StandaForm" solved it.

Comment: does `ToString[per, StandardForm]` solve your issue?

Comment: Neither the code in your post nor the one in your image seem to work. Could you fix the code text?

Comment: you probably meant `l=10; click=0; per:= 39176(click/l);` ? (Note the definition of `per` using  `SetDelayed`).

Comment: @MarcoB sorry, I already fixed it.

Comment: @kglr Thanks!!! StandardForm worked, now there's a beatiful fraction instead.

Comment: Mara, posted the comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define `p` using `SetDelayed` and use `ToString[p, StandardForm]`:

```
l = 10; click = 0;
p := 39176 (click/l);

Row[{Button["Yes", click++], Button["No"], 
  Button["End game", 
   m = StringJoin["You played with ", ToString[l], " ", 
     " words, and you know ", ToString[click], 
     " words.\nThe Mathematica\.b4s WordList has 39176 words, so you
   technically know ", ToString[p, StandardForm], " words."]; Print[m]]}]
```

[image]